# How to get average value over last N hours in Prometheus

Tags: go, prometheus, metrics, promql

In Prometheus I want to calculate the total average of this specific power metric (`dell_hw_chassis_power_reading`) within a period of time. For example, the last 2 hours.

I currently am using this query below:

```
sum(avg_over_time(dell_hw_chassis_power_reading[2h])) by (node,instance)
```

This query seems to only give me the latest value within that 2-hour interval specified in the query. It does not give me the total average for all scrapes of that metric within the 2-hours.

Answer (score 0):

The query `avg_over_time(dell_hw_chassis_power_reading[2h])` returns the average values for raw samples stored in Prometheus over the last 2 hours. If Prometheus contains multiple time series with the `dell_hw_chassis_power_reading` name, then the query would return independent averages per each matching time series.

If you want calculating the average over all the time series with the name `dell_hw_chassis_power_reading`, then the following query must be used:

```
sum(sum_over_time(dell_hw_chassis_power_reading[2h]))
  /
sum(count_over_time(dell_hw_chassis_power_reading[2h]))
```

If you need the average per some label or a set of labels, then the following query must be used:

```
sum(sum_over_time(dell_hw_chassis_power_reading[2h])) by (labels)
  /
sum(count_over_time(dell_hw_chassis_power_reading[2h])) by (labels)
```

Comment: This query you have suggested still seems to be only giving me the most recent time series value. I am looking for an average of the all the time series in let's say as an example the last 1 hour.